# Each object is stored separately in useState React | how to store in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I written code a dynamic form whose codes are given below, but my problem is in storing it in the useState `formFields` , which is stored in an array / Each object is stored separately, but I want them to be stored in an array ‍‍`question`.

this is my input:

```
[
{ titleQuestion: "aaa", metric: "bbb", subMetrico: "ccc" },
{ titleQuestion: "bbb", metric: "bbb", subMetrico: "ccc" },
{ titleQuestion: "ccc", metric: "bbb", subMetrico: "ccc" }
]
```

but i want to be like this:

```
{
    "quetions": [
          { titleQuestion: "aaa", metric: "bbb", subMetrico: "ccc" },
          { titleQuestion: "bbb", metric: "bbb", subMetrico: "ccc" },
          { titleQuestion: "ccc", metric: "bbb", subMetrico: "ccc" }
        
    ],
}
```

​
this is my all code:

```
  const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState([])

  // Add Question
  const handleFormChange = (event, index) => {
    let data = [...formFields];
    // data[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setFormFields(data);
  }

  const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formFields)
  }

  const addFields = () => {
    let object = {
      titleQuestion: '',
      metric: '',
      subMetrico:''
    }

    setFormFields([...formFields, object])
  }

  const removeFields = (index) => {
    let data = [...formFields];
    data.splice(index, 1)
    setFormFields(data)
  }
```

and:

```
<div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={submit}>
        {formFields.map((form, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <input
                name='titleQuestion'
                onChange={event => handleFormChange(event, index)}
                value={form.titleQuestion}
              />
              <input
                name='metric'
                onChange={event => handleFormChange(event, index)}
                value={form.metric}
              />
               <input
                name='subMetric'
                onChange={event => handleFormChange(event, index)}
                value={form.subMetric}
              />
              <button onClick={() => removeFields(index)}>Remove</button>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </form>
      <button onClick={addFields}>+</button>
      <br />
      <button onClick={submit}>submit</button>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
{
    "quetions": [
          { titleQuestion: "aaa", metric: "bbb", subMetrico: "ccc" },
          { titleQuestion: "bbb", metric: "bbb", subMetrico: "ccc" },
          { titleQuestion: "ccc", metric: "bbb", subMetrico: "ccc" }

    ],
     "post_id":10
}
```

Comment: You're initialising `formFields` as an array, so you get an array... if you want an object, then initialise it with an object. Moreover, this sounds like an XY problem: even if you're storing in as an array now, nothing is stopping you from transforming it into an object later if you need to pass it on for other uses.

Comment: @Terry Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant Thank you. If you can, please edit my code so that I can understand my mistake

Comment: I edited the code he means for you

Comment: Note that I just everywhere referenced your array inside an object with a `questions` key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the following functions so that your array is stored inside the `questions` key in the object

```
  const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState({})

  // Add Question
  const handleFormChange = (event, index) => {
    let data = [...formFields.quetions];
    // data.quetions[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setFormFields({ quetions: data });
  }

      const addFields = () => {
        let object = {
          titleQuestion: '',
          metric: '',
          subMetrico:''
        }
    
        if(formFields.quetions)
            setFormFields({ quetions: [...formFields.quetions, object] });
        else 
            setFormFields({ quetions: [object] });
      }

  const removeFields = (index) => {
    let data = [...formFields.quetions];
    data.splice(index, 1)
    setFormFields({ quetions: data })
  }
```

Comment: but this error show me : `Uncaught TypeError: formFields.map is not a function` i think because we convert array to object in state

Comment: You should now write like this: `formFields.questions.map` because your array is now stored inside the `questions` key in the object

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, I'd appreciate it if you marked it as the correct answer

Comment: still have error : `Uncaught TypeError: formFields.questions is undefined`

Comment: This is because in the first run there is no key named `questions`, you can fix this by initializing this key at the beginning like this:  `const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState({questions: []})`
  Or add a question mark in the map in the following way: `formFields.questions?.map`

Comment: If you use typescript then you cannot use the second solution, you can write like this: `formFields.questions && formFields.questions.map`

Comment: it's ok in console but when i click on `+` same `addFields`, don't show me inputs

Comment: Can you print to the console the value of `formFields` after you press `+` and send here?

Comment: after two click =  `Object { quetions: (2) […] }
​
quetions: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​​
0: Object { titleQuestion: "", metric: "", subMetrico: "" }
​​
1: Object { titleQuestion: "", metric: "", subMetrico: "" }
​​
length: 2`

Comment: Note that your key is `quetions`, and in the map I wrote `questions` by mistake (or in the initialization of the `usestate` from the previous comment), please correct everything to the exact same keyword

Comment: thanks a lot , if i want to add add another key and value to my object i can do that (foe example post_id)?

i updated my question and insert simple of that

Comment: Yes you can of course, I hope I understood your question correctly.
I would appreciate it if you marked my answer above as the correct answer :)

Comment: i insert update

Comment: Thank you very much, good luck with your project

Comment: can you answer plesae my update question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248835/discussion-between-haim-abeles-and-ariana).

Comment: i have a issue , input not working , when i click on input i can't type anything in input

Comment: @Ariana It would be great if you open a proper question and send me a link here so that it can help someone in the future with such a problem

Comment: It's really hard for me to rewrite the codes in other question. Thank you for your help here

Comment: You can copy and paste, but try asking here, I hope I can understand

Comment: i say y problem , have a issue , input not working , when i click on input i can't type anything in input

Comment: Note that the editing of your state is by typing in the input in the comment
    `// data[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;`

Comment: yes it's working but when i click on submit these are empty `titleQuestion: "", metric: "", subMetrico: "" `

Comment: what does the `console.log(formFields)` print in the `submit` function?

Comment: `Object { questions: (2) […], test_id: null }
​
questions: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​​
0: Object { titleQuestion: "", metric: "", subMetrico: "" }
​​​
metric: ""
​​​
subMetrico: ""
​​​
titleQuestion: ""
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
1: Object { titleQuestion: "", metric: "", subMetrico: "" }
​​​
metric: ""
​​​
subMetrico: ""
​​​
titleQuestion: ""
​`

Comment: And did you remove from the comment the code I sent earlier?

Comment: no i don't delete

Comment: This code should not be in a comment, it is the cause of your problem

Comment: it's not comment but same issue , still are null

Comment: You can edit all the code here in the question so that it is exactly the same as your code? it's hard to answer when it's not organized

Comment: thanks . i changed to `data[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;` it's working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74264906/nested-dynamic-form-how-to-define-another-dynamic-form-in-dynamic-form i hope you can help me with this question

Comment: Sorry, I've been unavailable for a few days and now I can't find your question, did you manage?

Comment: can you help me for this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74335570/how-to-define-state-or-object-to-send-data-with-post-api-in-react